# Клик по динамически создаваемым элементам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующее:

```
<form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="table" placeholder="имя таблицы">
        <div class="column_rows" id="c_rows">
            <div class="row" id="r1">
                <input type="text" name="name_field" placeholder="имя поля">
                <select name="type_field">
                    <option default="default" value="0">Выбор типа</option>
                    <option value="1">Текстовое поле</option>
                    <option value="2">числовое поле</option>
                    <option value="3">дата</option>
                </select>
                <input type="number" name="chars_field" placeholder="Ограничение по количеству символов если есть">
                <button type="button" id="ab1" data-add="1">+</button>
                <button type="button" id="rb1" data-remove="1">-</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">тык</button>
    </form>
```

Выглядит вот так вот:
[image: фронт]

при клике на `+` еще одно поле добавляется, при клике на `-` - удаляется.

Получается подобный HTML:

```
<div class="column_rows" id="c_rows">
            <div class="row" id="r1">
                <input type="text" name="name_field" placeholder="имя поля">
                <select name="type_field">
                    <option default="default" value="0">Выбор типа</option>
                    <option value="1">Текстовое поле</option>
                    <option value="2">числовое поле</option>
                    <option value="3">дата</option>
                </select>
                <input type="number" name="chars_field" placeholder="Ограничение по количеству символов если есть">
                <button type="button" id="ab1" data-add="1">+</button>
                <button type="button" id="rb1" data-remove="1">-</button>
            </div>
        <div class="row" id="r2">    <input type="text" name="name_field" placeholder="имя поля">
                <select name="type_field">
                    <option default="default" value="0">Выбор типа</option>
                    <option value="1">Текстовое поле</option>
                    <option value="2">числовое поле</option>
                    <option value="3">дата</option>
                </select>
                <input type="number" name="chars_field" placeholder="Ограничение по количеству символов если есть">
                <button type="button" id="ab2" data-add="2">+</button>
                <button type="button" id="rb2" data-remove="2">-</button>
            </div><div class="row" id="r3">    <input type="text" name="name_field" placeholder="имя поля">
                <select name="type_field">
                    <option default="default" value="0">Выбор типа</option>
                    <option value="1">Текстовое поле</option>
                    <option value="2">числовое поле</option>
                    <option value="3">дата</option>
                </select>
                <input type="number" name="chars_field" placeholder="Ограничение по количеству символов если есть">
                <button type="button" id="ab3" data-add="3">+</button>
                <button type="button" id="rb3" data-remove="3">-</button>
            </div><div class="row" id="r4">    <input type="text" name="name_field" placeholder="имя поля">
                <select name="type_field">
                    <option default="default" value="0">Выбор типа</option>
                    <option value="1">Текстовое поле</option>
                    <option value="2">числовое поле</option>
                    <option value="3">дата</option>
                </select>
                <input type="number" name="chars_field" placeholder="Ограничение по количеству символов если есть">
                <button type="button" id="ab4" data-add="4">+</button>
                <button type="button" id="rb4" data-remove="4">-</button>
            </div><div class="row" id="r5">    <input type="text" name="name_field" placeholder="имя поля">
                <select name="type_field">
                    <option default="default" value="0">Выбор типа</option>
                    <option value="1">Текстовое поле</option>
                    <option value="2">числовое поле</option>
                    <option value="3">дата</option>
                </select>
                <input type="number" name="chars_field" placeholder="Ограничение по количеству символов если есть">
                <button type="button" id="ab5" data-add="5">+</button>
                <button type="button" id="rb5" data-remove="5">-</button>
            </div></div>
```

Кнопка добавить первом элементе, (который статически есть) - работают, на остальных - нет. Для кнопки удаления еще не писал код.
Пробовал решить так как было описано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/631381/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-jquery). У каждой кнопки свой id + `$(document).ready()..` - не помогло.

Как по мне причина в том что клик происходит по элементу которого якобы нет, так как он динамически создавался, думал делегирование эту проблему решит - но возник другой вопрос, как объяснить к какому элементу нужно обратиться при делегировании если мы не знаем на какой элемент может быть клик. В общем как это можно разрулить?

Код добавления:

```
$('[id^="ab"]').click(function () {
       let ThisCount = $(this).attr('data-add');
       let last = $('#c_rows').children().last();
       let LastCount = last.children('button').attr('data-add');
       LastCount = Number(LastCount);
       let ItemCount = (LastCount + 1);
       let row = '<div class="row" id="r' + ItemCount +'"\n>'+
           '    <input type="text" name="name_field" placeholder="имя поля">\n' +
           '                <select name="type_field">\n' +
           '                    <option default="default" value="0">Выбор типа</option>\n' +
           '                    <option value="1">Текстовое поле</option>\n' +
           '                    <option value="2">числовое поле</option>\n' +
           '                    <option value="3">дата</option>\n' +
           '                </select>\n' +
           '                <input type="number" name="chars_field" placeholder="Ограничение по количеству символов если есть">\n' +
           '                <button type="button" id="ab' + ItemCount + '" data-add="' + ItemCount + '">+</button>\n' +
           '                <button type="button" id="rb' + ItemCount + '" data-remove="' + ItemCount + '">-</button>\n' +
           '            </div>';
       $('#c_rows').append(row);
    });
```

Попытка делегирования

```
$('#c_rows').on('click', $('[id^="ab"]'), function () {
        console.log(this);
        alert("32");
    });
```

Comment: вторым параметром в `on` идет сам селектор, а не `$`. И замените этот ваш `id^=` на класс

Comment: ну так а разница? что класс, что id - надо динамически создавать и разные.

Comment: @Антон класс у вас будет один. например `add-btn`. и тогда код будет такой `$('#c_rows').on('click', '.add-btn', function....`

Comment: так а разве в таком случае клик не будет делегироваться на все классы? Мне ведь нужно получить дата атрибут той кнопки на которую кликнули чтобы увеличить это число на 1, и создать новую строку. В принципе в коде расписано.

Comment: @Антон внутри обработчика, чтобы обратиться к дата атрибуту кликнутой кнопки надо будет взять `$(this)`.... который при клике в конкретном контексте будет указывать на конкретную кнопку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше не дублировать `id` по коду, а по поводу неработающих кнопок, то я вижу выход добавить класс `add-btn` на кнопку и селектор поменять на `document on click`, тогда всё работает, вот минимально изменный ваш пример:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add-btn', function () {
       let ThisCount = $(this).attr('data-add');
       let last = $('#c_rows').children().last();
       let LastCount = last.children('button').attr('data-add');
       LastCount = Number(LastCount);
       let ItemCount = (LastCount + 1);
       let row = '<div class="row" id="r' + ItemCount +'"\n>'+
           '    <input type="text" name="name_field" placeholder="имя поля">\n' +
           '                <select name="type_field">\n' +
           '                    <option default="default" value="0">Выбор типа</option>\n' +
           '                    <option value="1">Текстовое поле</option>\n' +
           '                    <option value="2">числовое поле</option>\n' +
           '                    <option value="3">дата</option>\n' +
           '                </select>\n' +
           '                <input type="number" name="chars_field" placeholder="Ограничение по количеству символов если есть">\n' +
           '                <button type="button" class="add-btn" id="ab' + ItemCount + '" data-add="' + ItemCount + '">+</button>\n' +
           '                <button type="button" id="rb' + ItemCount + '" data-remove="' + ItemCount + '">-</button>\n' +
           '            </div>';
       $('#c_rows').append(row);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
        <input type="text" name="table" placeholder="имя таблицы">
        <div class="column_rows" id="c_rows">
            <div class="row" id="r1">
                <input type="text" name="name_field" placeholder="имя поля">
                <select name="type_field">
                    <option default="default" value="0">Выбор типа</option>
                    <option value="1">Текстовое поле</option>
                    <option value="2">числовое поле</option>
                    <option value="3">дата</option>
                </select>
                <input type="number" name="chars_field" placeholder="Ограничение по количеству символов если есть">
                <button type="button" class="add-btn" id="ab1" data-add="1">+</button>
                <button type="button" id="rb1" data-remove="1">-</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">тык</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: и зачем на `document` вешать? обработчик вешается на самого ближайшего общего предка.

Comment: Обычно так использую при динамическом DOM